FastAPI with SAM model: Only a few workers load properly due to CUDA memory error
I'm working on a project involving FastAPI with a Segment anything Model (SAM) for image processing. I have a CUDA setup with a GPU (NVIDIA RTX A4000) available for acceleration, and I'm running FastAPI with 15 workers. However, when I start the FastAPI server using the following CLI:
uvicorn server:app --port 5008 --host 0.0.0.0 --workers 15

only 3 to 5 workers load properly. I encountered a CUDA memory error for the remaining workers indicating that the memory is insufficient. The specific error message I receive is:
"RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate X MiB"
I've tried loading the SAM model when the workers start up, but I still face the same issue with workers running out of CUDA memory. Is there a way I can configure FastAPI or the workers to use the available CUDA memory more efficiently so that I can utilize all 15 workers without running into memory errors?
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on optimizing the CUDA memory usage for all workers in FastAPI. Thank you!

Perhaps your SAM should be a service with a queue that is called by your webserver rather than directly part of it.

I did not understand what exactly you meant by SAM should be a service with a queue, Can you please explain this?

I recommend you look at separating the AI from your web application. The AI task might them be implemented as an API call that leveraged a queue so that only a limited number of AI tasks were active at any one time. Once a task was completed the results would be delivered async to the end user.

My task is quite quick—it completes in just a second or two. Because of this, I've decided to implement an API.
